# NewLine does not appear in the browser validation message

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a input as below with a pattern

```
$('#charEntry').append("<input type='text' class='form-control' id='chars"+i+"' pattern='(?=.*\\\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-+*/%])(?=.*[.?,:;-~]).*' " +
            "title='Your String Must Contain: &#010;" +
            "One Upper Case Value &#x0a;" +
            " One Lower-Case Value &#010;" +
            " One Arithmetic Value &#010;" +
            " One Punctuation Character &#010;" +
            " One Numeric Value'" +
            "  maxlength='" +charLength + "'" +
            " minlength='" +charLength + "'   required>");
```

However in the actual message the new lines would not get printed as below.
[image]

I have tried 
 , \n and &#010 but nothing works.
is there a fix for this?

Comment: do the lines show up in the title? (aka tooltip)

Comment: @dandavis Yes they do.Yeah figured as much.
Thank you

Comment: If they appear in title but not the error, then that's just how the browser chooses to show the messages, nothing you can do about it other than to show/hide a div with custom formatted feedback when validation state changes.